# Configure Odata service through app.config

Tags: wcf-data-services, odata

I am selfhosting an OData application. This currently involves a lot of hard-coding: In my DataService class itself:

```
public static void InitializeService(
           DataServiceConfiguration config)
        {
            // Provide read-only access to all entries and feeds. 
            config.SetEntitySetAccessRule(
               "*", EntitySetRights.AllRead);
            config.SetServiceOperationAccessRule("*", ServiceOperationRights.AllRead);

            config.UseVerboseErrors = true;
            config.DataServiceBehavior.MaxProtocolVersion = System.Data.Services.Common.DataServiceProtocolVersion.V2;
        }
```

and when initialising:

```
 Type servicetype = typeof(MessageDataService);
 Uri baseaddress = new Uri("http://localhost:8000/messageData");
 Uri[] baseaddresses = new Uri[] { baseaddress };
 using ( DataServiceHost dshost = new DataServiceHost(servicetype, baseaddresses))
 {
   dshost.Open();
   //blah
 }
```

I think this can be adequately summorised with "yuk". Now I can configure other WCF services neatly through `App.config`. Is there anything out of the box for Data services too, or should I roll my own configuration classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WCF Data Services currently doesn't read any configuration from the config files. So rolling your own solution is the way to go.

Comment: Yeah - kind of true. Although I wouldn't count the instantiation of the host as part of WCF Data Services (that is entirely in the ownership of the generic WCF). But that's pretty much the only thing you can configure through the config files.

Answer (score 3):

You can do all the configuration in app.config. It is just a bit awkward...:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="MyBindingName" >
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
      <service name="{you service type name including the namespace i.e. myapplication.myservice}">
        <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="MyBindingName" contract="System.Data.Services.IRequestHandler">
        </endpoint>
      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

In your code you then instantiate the host without any specific url. It will pick it from the config as usual:

```
var host = new DataServiceHost(typeof(YourServiceType), new Uri[0]);
```

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2543719/80941) for detailed answer.