# Self-hosted WCF Data service authentication

Tags: .net, wcf, wcf-data-services, self-hosting

I have self-hosted WCF Data service set up in similar way to this - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/writingdata_services/archive/2011/01/24/self-hosting-a-wcf-data-service.aspx

How does one add Windows authentication on top of this?

I know how to add it in IIS however self-hosted scenario is escaping me...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to use app.config and configure all the security settings there...:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="MyBindingName" >
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
      <service name="{you service type name including the namespace i.e. myapplication.myservice}">
        <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="MyBindingName" contract="System.Data.Services.IRequestHandler">
        </endpoint>
      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2543719/80941) for detailed answer.