# How to use authentication with self hosted WCF OData service

Tags: c#, wcf, authentication, odata, wcf-data-services

I have an WCF DataService that runs inside a console application with `DataServiceHost`

I can sucessfully start my host and query my WCF DataService with this code

```
public void Start()
{
    var uri = new Uri("http://localhost:12345/Products");
    var host = new DataServideHost(typeof(ProductsDataService), uri);
    if (host.Description.Behaviors.Find<ServiceMetadataBehavior>() == null)
        host.Description.Behaviors.Add(new ServiceMetadataBehavior());
    if (host.Description.Behaviors.Find<ServiceDebugBehavior>() == null)
        host.Description.Behaviors.Add(new ServiceDebugBehavior());
    host.Description.Behaviors.Find<ServiceMetadataBehavior()
        .HttpGetEnabled = true;
    host.Description.Behaviors.Find<ServiceDebugBehavior>()
        .IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true;

    host.AddServiceEndpoint(
        new ServiceEndpoint(ContractDescription.GetContract(serviceType))
        {
            Name = "default",
            Address = new EndpointAddress(baseAddress),
            Contract = ContractDescription.GetContract(
                typeof(IRequestHandler)),
            Binding = new WebHttpBinding(),
        });

    host.Open();
}
```

How I want to secure this service with basic authentication or something else (note that my service will be secured by https)

I found plenty examples on how to secure a DataService with IIS using a `IHttpModule` however I also found post that say I can't use HttpModules with my DataServiceHost.

Can someone please give me a hint on how to implement authentication?

Comment: Please refer to this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15410937/self-hosted-wcf-data-service-authentication. Hope it helpful

Comment: @LaylaLiuMSFT Thanks, good to know this is an option. Since I don't use the `app.config` file I would have to modify the binding (`var binding = new WebHttpBinding(WebHttpSecurityMode.TransportCredentialOnly); binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Basic;` via code.
However I found a great solution with server side hooks that give me much more control (see my answer) and since I want to authenticate against a usertable in my DbContext anyway this fits my needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the blog post [OData and Authentication – Part 4 – Server Side Hooks](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/odatateam/archive/2010/07/19/odata-and-authentication-part-4-server-side-hooks.aspx) I created an extension method to use with DataServices. Please keep in mind that you shold only use basic auth over HTTPS or your password will be visible to others since username / password are just base64 decoded. For testing purpose you can remove this check `if (!context.Request.IsSecureConnection) return false;`

Usage:

```
public ProductsDataService : EntityFrameworkDataService<ProductsContext>
{
    private static validator = new UserValidator();
    public ProductsDataService()
    {
        this.UseBasicAuthentification("My Realm", validator);
    }

    private class UserValidator : IUserValidator
    {
        public IPrincipal Validate(string username, string password)
        {
            // just an example implementation
            if (!"1234".Equals(password)) retur null;
            return new GenericPrincipal(
                new GenericIdentity(username), "Admin", "User");
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the implementation. You just have to create a IUserValidator implementation that fits your needs.

```
public static class DataServiceExtensions
{

    public static void UseBasicAuthentification<T>(
        this DataService<T> service, string realm, IUserValidator validator)
    {
        service.ProcessingPipeline.ProcessingRequest += (_sender, _e) =>
        {
            if (!Authenticate(_e.OperationContext, validator))
            {
                _e.OperationContext.ResponseHeaders.Add(
                     "WWW-Authenticate", "Basic realm=" + 
                        Convert.ToBase64String(
                        Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(GlobalConfiguration.Realm)));
                throw new DataServiceException(401, "401 Unauthorized");
            }
        };
    }

    static bool Authenticate(DataServiceOperationContext context,
        IUserValidator validator)
    {
        if (!context.RequestHeaders.AllKeys.Contains("Authorization"))
            return false;

        // Remember claims based security should be only be 
        // used over HTTPS  
        if (!context.Request.IsSecureConnection)
            return false;

        string authHeader = context.RequestHeaders["Authorization"];

        IPrincipal principal = null;
        if (TryGetPrincipal(authHeader, validator, out principal))
        {
            //context.User = principal;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    private static bool TryGetPrincipal(string authHeader,
        IUserValidator validator, out IPrincipal principal)
    {
        var protocolParts = authHeader.Split(' ');
        if (protocolParts.Length != 2)
        {
            principal = null;
            return false;
        }
        else if (protocolParts[0] == "Basic")
        {

            var parameter = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(
                Convert.FromBase64String(protocolParts[1]));
            var parts = parameter.Split(':');

            if (parts.Length != 2)
            {
                principal = null;
                return false;
            }

            var username = parts[0];
            var password = parts[1];

            principal = validator.Validate(username, password);

            return principal != null;
        }
        else
        {
            principal = null;
            return false;
        }
    }

}

public interface IUserValidator
{
    IPrincipal Validate(string username, string password);
}
```